# How to add text to slides using superslides?

Tags: jquery, plugins

This is an example of slider, how do i add text to each slide ? I haven't found any info about adding texts or other elements in github, any help or ideas would be appreciated.

```
<body>
  <div id="slides">
    <div class="slides-container">
      <img src="images/people.jpeg" alt="Cinelli">
      <img src="images/surly.jpeg" width="1024" height="682" alt="Surly">
      <img src="images/cinelli-front.jpeg" width="1024" height="683" alt="Cinelli">
      <img src="images/affinity.jpeg" width="1024" height="685" alt="Affinity">
      <img src="images/affinity.jpeg" width="1024" height="685" alt="Affinity">   
    </div>

    <nav class="slides-navigation">
      <a href="#" class="next">Next</a>
      <a href="#" class="prev">Previous</a>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/hammer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../dist/jquery.superslides.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var $slides = $('#slides');

      Hammer($slides[0]).on("swipeleft", function(e) {
        $slides.data('superslides').animate('next');
      });

      Hammer($slides[0]).on("swiperight", function(e) {
        $slides.data('superslides').animate('prev');
      });

      $slides.superslides({
        hashchange: true
      });
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Tried to wrap image in div and <p> tag, setting p to be fixed position. Did nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation and inspecting a DEMO example, you can add text using the following structure for the **slides-container**:

```
<ul class="slides-container">
  <li>
    <img src="http://flickholdr.com/1000/800" alt="">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Text for the first slide</h2> <!-- You can use any tag you want here -->
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://flickholdr.com/1000/800/space" alt="">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Text for the second slide</h2> <!-- You can use any tag you want here -->
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://flickholdr.com/1000/800/tech" alt="">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Text for the third slide</h2> <!-- You can use any tag you want here -->
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your welcome, please, i will appreciate if you mark the answer as useful or correct when you have some time.

Comment: No prob mate. after 3 years